# Can't load database on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing

So I upgraded my Neo4j cluster instalation to 3.0.3 and it seems I can not load the database that comes with the instalation. This is the log file

```
<code>2016-06-28 14:11:20.879+0000 INFO  Starting...
2016-06-28 14:11:21.620+0000 INFO  Write transactions to database disabled
2016-06-28 14:11:22.483+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-06-28 14:11:22.504+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2016-06-28 14:11:24.344+0000 INFO  Attempting to join cluster of [192.168.1.91:5001, 192.168.1.92:5001, 192.168.1.93:5001]
2016-06-28 14:11:54.762+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingData$
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1f7853af' wa$
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:87)
        at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1f7853af' was succ$
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.ha.factory.HighlyAvailableFacadeFactory, /opt/neo4j/neo4j-enterprise$
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.factory.HighlyAvailableFacadeFactory.newFacade(HighlyAvailableFacadeFactory.java:42)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:41)
        at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$0(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin@4b6942a0' was successfully initia$
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachineProxyFactory$ResponseFuture.get(StateMachineProxyFactory.java:300)
</code>
```

Is there any fresh db I could try to load ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that on a single instance or cluster?

Best try it in standalone mode first.

How did you upgrade? Using the admin-tool with

`neo4j-admin --mode database --from neo4j-2x-db --to neo4j-3x-db` ?

- see: https://neo4j.com/guides/upgrade/#neo4j-3-0
- and: http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.0/#upgrade-instructions-2x

Comment: I removed the folder and I instaled the new version.